# Remove bunch of disconnected LUNs by shell script (regex issue)

Tags: regex, shell-scripting, scsi, lun, remove

Have a problem with my script, don't want to run same procedure 200 times with changing LUN number.
Remove the multipath device from ALL paths to the LUN, run `echo 1 > /sys/bus/scsi/devices/${H:B:T:L}/delete`  (Where H = host:B = bus:T = target:L = lun)
For example, 2:0:3:1 till 2:0:3:49

Let's check our LUNs:

```
lsscsi


[2:0:3:33]   disk    NETAPP   LUN C-Mode       9700  /dev/sdbt
[2:0:3:34]   disk    NETAPP   LUN C-Mode       9700  /dev/sdbv
[2:0:3:35]   disk    NETAPP   LUN C-Mode       9700  /dev/sdbw
[2:0:3:36]   disk    NETAPP   LUN C-Mode       9700  /dev/sdby
[2:0:3:37]   disk    NETAPP   LUN C-Mode       9700  /dev/sdca
[2:0:3:38]   disk    NETAPP   LUN C-Mode       9700  /dev/sdcc
[2:0:3:39]   disk    NETAPP   LUN C-Mode       9700  /dev/sdce
[2:0:3:40]   disk    NETAPP   LUN C-Mode       9700  /dev/sdcg
[2:0:3:41]   disk    NETAPP   LUN C-Mode       9700  /dev/sdci
[2:0:3:42]   disk    NETAPP   LUN C-Mode       9700  /dev/sdck
[2:0:3:43]   disk    NETAPP   LUN C-Mode       9700  /dev/sdcm
[2:0:3:44]   disk    NETAPP   LUN C-Mode       9700  /dev/sdco
[2:0:3:45]   disk    NETAPP   LUN C-Mode       9700  /dev/sdcp
```

Script to clean up:

```
for IP in {1...45} ; do 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/scsi/devices/2:0:3:$IP/delete'; done
```

Getting error:

```
-bash: echo 1 > /sys/bus/scsi/devices/2:0:3:$IP/delete: No such file or directory
```

Another try:

```
for IP in {1...45} ; do "echo 1 > /sys/bus/scsi/devices/2:0:3:$IP/delete"; done
```

Getting error:

```
-bash: echo 1 > /sys/bus/scsi/devices/2:0:3:{1...45}/delete: No such file or directory
```

How to isolate **$IP** to make it works in that request?

Answer (score 0):

You have `{1...45}`, but the syntax seems to be `{1..45}`. https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion